UK Address for service
Let us consider a hypothetical legal dispute which takes place in the UK.
The plaintiff wants to pursue a small claim against a large company that operates in several countries. The company's website lists the contact address as a post office box in another country.
However, the company may have a local office located only a couple of miles from where the plaintiff lives.
Could the plaintiff list the local office as the address for service on the claim?
It's for a story I'm writing.

I'll just put this here

There's no need to keep repeating "hypothetical". Unless your question is worded in the first person, it's assumed to be generic and won't be closed as requesting personal legal advice.

@littleadv That looks like an answer to me.

So what's the answer? Is that a yes or a no?
